# I want to use custom function for sign up in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use custom function in my android application for sign up in firebase. Currently I am using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function. It takes two parameters by default i.e Email & Password but my sign up form includes other attributes also like, phone number, name etc. So what should I do? Currently I am using the below code.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

if(task.isSuccessful())           
{

                progressDialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Registration Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Could Not Register. Try Again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Thank You :)

Comment: better to write the data i.e. name, phone etc. in firebase database by creating user node. in first activity take email and password from user and on successful creation ask them to fill the profile data i.e name, phone etc.

Comment: or use custom token for authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth